# C'è un equivalente italiano per il dialettale "non confondiamo l'oro con la tolla"?

Tags: word-meaning, idioms

Nel tradurre in inglese la frase *non confondiamo l'oro con la tolla*, ho scoperto che *tolla*, in realtà, è un'espressione dialettale  (in italiano sarebbe *latta*).

*Non confondiamo l'oro con la latta*, però, mi suona male.

Esiste un equivalente italiano per questo modo di dire?

Comment: Btw, what's the English traslation that best fits the proverb?

Comment: @Gio I've translated it literally but it wasn't a "formal" situation. If someone knows it, I'm pleased to know it, too!

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is no close equivalent  expression, maybe a question for ELU.

Comment: @Gio Asked: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/380582/183634

Comment: Good one, I've upvoted it.

Comment: Ho sentito dire qualche volta il colorito “non confondiamo la merda con la cioccolata”, ma non saprei dire quanto sia diffuso.

Comment: @DaG :):):) beh, diciamo che con la lana e la seta è un pochino più fine...

Comment: @Gio "Popular question" on ELU hahaha!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***"Non confondiamo la lana con la seta"*** è un modo di dire comune che penso abbia il significato che cerchi.

Questo modo di dire sembra abbia origini napoletane:

***“Nun ammiscamme ‘a lana c’ ‘a seta”*** è un proverbio napoletano ed è un invito a non confondere le cose, anche se possono sembrare simili, altrimenti ne scaturisce un danno.

Comment: _Non confondiamo l'oro con la tolla_ implica un avvertimento a non confondere una cosa di grande valore (l'oro) con una che vale poco (la tolla). Penso che proverbio che hai indicato abbia lo stesso significato (seta=oro, lana=tolla). Non l'avevo mai sentito, probabilmente perché si usa al sud.

Comment: @CarLaTeX - io vivo al nord e lo sento usare spesso. Probabilmente al sud, visto le origini napoletane, è più comune. Al contrario "l'oro con la tolla" mi è nuovo. Che dialetto è?

Comment: Allora mi sa che la _tolla_ è più frequente solo nel milanese!

Comment: "Faccia di tolla" è comune, anche in italiano. http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/tolla.php

Comment: Anche, ahahah ;)

Comment: A Taranto usiamo "No misckame scuércele cu fafe" trad. Non mischiamo le bucce dalle fave (ma non so se vale per l'italiano o è solo la traduzione)

Answer (score 4):

Altre espressioni simili possono essere:

***Non mischiare il sacro con il profano*** ovvero:

> mescolare insieme cose, persone o anche idee eterogenee o addirittura
>   contrastanti, che comunque non hanno niente a che vedere le une con le
>   altre. Anche semplicemente confonderle, far confusione.

oppure (simile a quello indicato da Gio)

***Vediamo di non mischiare gli stracci con la seta***

Comment: Come senso penso sia più vicina la frase con gli stracci e la seta, perché quella con l'oro e la tolla implica il confronto tra una cosa pregiata ed una senza valore, mentre quella con sacro e profano dà più l'idea del serio/scherzoso o qualcosa del genere (almeno questa è la mia impressione).

Comment: +1 Di tutte le espressioni che leggo in questa pagina, secondo me Sacro / Profano è l'unica che può essere considerata al 100% italiano e che si usa in tutta Italia. Le altre (oro / latta, lana / seta, stracci / seta, faccia di tolla) secondo me sono altamente regionali, non ne ho mai sentita nessuna in tanti anni in Italia.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @SantiBailors.